# posix sh: how to count number of occurrences in a string without using external tools?

Tags: sh, posix

In bash, it can be done like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

query='bengal'
string_to_search='bengal,toyger,bengal,persian,bengal'

delimiter='|'

replace_queries="${string_to_search//"$query"/"$delimiter"}"

delimiter_count="${replace_queries//[^"$delimiter"]}"
delimiter_count="${#delimiter_count}"

echo "Found $delimiter_count occurences of \"$query\""
```

Output:

```
Found 3 occurences of "bengal"
```

The caveat of course is that the delimiter cannot occur in 'query' or 'string_to_search'.

In POSIX sh, string replacement is not supported. Is there a way this can be done in POSIX sh using only shell builtins?

Comment: You can use `${string_to_search#*$delimiter}`

Comment: Your quest to replace Bash with POSIX `sh` has generated some vaguely interesting questions, but a pattern begins to emerge: you are discovering the features of POSIX apparently without actually learning to use them properly. Your question quality will steadily degrade as we show you over and over how to use the same primitives to accomplish different tasks. There's a reason the Bash maintainers decided to implement these features, you know; often, it was to reduce tedium.

Comment: @tripleee I take your meaning. I will stop asking questions about posix sh. Might you know where I can learn about these primitives? I wish there was a wooledge guide for posix sh, I have struggled to find good and reliable learning material

Comment: This is not to dissuade you from asking, and you might note that there are no downvotes on your question. I'd just like to encourage you to think about the features you have learned so far, and how they might be used to solve your remaining problems. These are Bash-compatible features, so you can get pretty far with Bash-oriented learning materials. I can't point to specific duplicates for the remaining "how do I reimplement Bash feature X in POSIX `sh`" but many of them *have* been asked before, or have reasonably discoverable duplicates about concrete problems like `PATH` manipulation etc.

Comment: The uppercase/lowercase path expanions in Bash are particularly tedious to reimplement but again, the small set of parameter expansion primitives in `sh` worked reasonably well for a long time for many people; it's rarely very hard to see how to use them to reimplement many of the Bash-only ones.

Comment: for learning *everything* about posix sh, I can recommend reading ... POSIX :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it...

```
#!/bin/sh

query='bengal'
string_to_search='bengal,toyger,bengal,persian,bengal'

i=0
process_string="$string_to_search"
while [ -n "$process_string" ]; do
    case "$process_string" in
        *"$query"*)
            process_string="${process_string#*"$query"}"
            i="$(( i + 1 ))"
            ;;
        *)
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "Found $i occurences of \"$query\""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

query='bengal'
string_to_search='bengal,toyger,bengal,persian,bengal'

ct() (
        n=0
        IFS=,
        q=$1
        set $2
        for t in "$@"; do
                if [ "$t" = "$q" ]; then
                        n=$((n + 1))
                fi
        done
        echo $n
)

n=$(ct "$query" "$string_to_search")
printf "found %d %s\n" $n $query
```

Though I'm not sure what the point is.  If you've got a posix shell,
you also almost certainly have printf, sed, grep, and wc.

```
printf '%s\n' "$string_to_search" | sed -e 's/,/\n/g' | grep -Fx "$query" | wc -l
```